# Jquery - get last li element after caching ul

Tags: jquery

I know to get the last child of a list, you do this:

```
$('ul li:last-child');
```

In my case though I need to cache the ul as it's used multiple times:

```
var ul = $('ul#news-list');
```

How do i then get the last child of the cached element ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var ul = $('#news-list');
ul.find('li:last-child')
```

*Since you are using id selector, don't use the element selector with it*

Comment: +1 this as it's right, but the comment about not using the element type in the selector isn't correct.  I've had this discussion with people before and there are some rare cases where it's relevant to include the element type.  We might not like it, but there are cases.

Comment: @Archer can you give any references... in normal cases it is not required as ID will be unique exception in cases in which if the you want to make sure that the element with is of type div/span or something like that....

Comment: That's exactly the reason that it is relevant - checking that the element with the given id *is* of a specific type.  The example I've used before (which is lame, but explains) is a table where one of the columns may have plain text or an input.  You can then check `$("input#row15").length` to see if row15 is an editable row.  It can be useful to cut down on extra code, but obviously only has very limited uses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ul = $('ul#news-list');
var li = $('li:last-child', ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var child=$('#news-list').find('li:last-child');
```

Answer (score 0):

**in single line**

```
$('ul#news-list').find('li:last-child');
```

**and you can use**

```
var ul = $('ul#news-list');
var li = $('li:last-child', ul); //or
var li  =ul.find('li:last-child');
```

reference **[:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)** and **[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**